# How to "clone" branch as one commit?

Tags: git

So I have the `dev` branch which currently has a lot of `temp` commits. Is it possible somehow to merge all those commits in to one? Or recreate branch with code from last commit as a new one?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. If you have following situation:

```
a--b--c (dev)
\
 d--e (temp)
```

the command

```
git merge --squash branchname
```

will result in

```
a--b--c--f
```

where `f` contains the changes done in `d` and `e`

Answer (score 1):

**Two ways**

*1. This will create a new branch -*

Step 1:
create a new branch from where you have created `dev` branch

```
git checkout master
git branch -d new_branch
```

Step 2:
checkout to that branch

```
git checkout new_branch
```

step 3:
merge dev with --squash flag

```
git merge --squash dev
```

step 4:
`add` `commit` and `push`

```
git add .
git commit -m'commit message'
git push origin new_branch
```

*2. One commit in same branch **(tricky way)***

`n` is number of commits you want to edit

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~n
```

here you can edit the commits and squish them in one commit

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a rebase in git.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Here is a git tutorial how to rebase a branch to remove unused commit messages.

Answer (score 0):

**[Simple solution:](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode)**

```
git rebase -i <after-this-commit>
```

[**Squash your commits**](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages)

Recently, I faced the same problem, I had 41 commits on my pull request, see [here](https://github.com/ShivaShinde/gspread/commit/120bad77928849e98586661669f3e34dd9b9240b). I will only touch something what I have implemented.

For instance, if you have 3 commits, you can squash them and make into one using interactive rebase. See below command:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~n
```

For example, you want to squash 3 commits:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Now, you see an interactive rebase interface, where you can write reword/pick on first commit and squash on rest of them. Please see this video for better understanding.

[Squashing commits video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IfkL8swmFw)

> This is easy, will not take longer. I worked on it.

See this post [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)